# Ventura 13.6 how to change default browser for sudo to firefox?

Tags: terminal, safari, firefox

I have set default browser under settings to Firefox so running `open 'https://google.com'` opens up firefox but running `sudo open 'https://google.com'` will still open safari browser

I have commands that require sudo user.

How do I change root default browser to use firefox? Clearly this should be an option

Os: ventura 13.6 / M2 Pro 2023

Comment: If you document how you changed the open application for your user it might provide a better answer and also teach others that trick :) no need to edit the question, just a suggestion to improve it for everyone

Answer (score 3):

When you run the `open` with `sudo` you are running as `root`. This means that Safari is launched by default.

To circumvent this, as the `-a` option to `open` thusly:

```
sudo open -a /Applications/Firefox.app https://google.com
```